# How do I set up a server with just javascript?

Tags: javascript, webserver

When I look this up, I get recommendations for node.js. But I don't want to use abstractions I don't understand. Is it possible to do with just javascript?

Comment: @elclanrs When I read the title, I thought "WTF impossubruuuu!" then I saw the downvotes and I was like "Hahahaha I am right!" then I saw your comment saying "Yes, it is possible." **Then I have nothing left to read/learn.** My brain has a huge question mark now lingering like a crazy monkey. **Answer, please?**

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?  How is this a bad question?

Comment: Can't tell if trolling or legit.

Comment: @Gapton. You can run a server in JS in just a few lines with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/).

Comment: @RyanBigg, Err on the side of legit... You don't find many trolling questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: `node.js` is too bulky for you? As far as web servers go, I cannot think of one which is lighter. Sure some may be faster or whatever. But a default node loadout is pretty skinny (many argue, too skinny).

Answer (score 3):

You need something to interpret and execute the JavaScript.  (To my knowledge, there is nothing that compiles JavaScript to a regular executable you can just run standalone.  Even if there were, you still need that compiler initially.)

Node.js uses Google's V8 engine for executing JavaScript, and provides a small library of functions.  You'll note that most of those functions are actually just JavaScript themselves.  (Many do have bindings to native code.

In short, sure it is possible, but not without a compiler or interpreter.  Node.js is the easiest way to get started.  Also, it isn't adding an extra layer of abstraction, and the built-in libraries are not loaded unless you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is the closest thing to "just JavaScript" you'll get. To execute JavaScript you need a JavaScript engine, and node.js supplies that in the form of Google's V8 Engine. If you want to run JavaScript on the server I'd say Node.js is the way to go.